# Button command not firing in listview group header

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a listview with an expandable header, this works correctly, however when I add a button in the  it doesn't fire the associated command.

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
        <Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="txtX" FontWeight="Bold"   Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                   <Button Content="Add Task List" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding XCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander.Header>
    <ItemsPresenter />
    </Expander>
</ControlTemplate>
```

All other buttons on the page fire commands correctly to my viewmodel, so i'm going to hazard a guess it's something related to the xaml, or the way in which the buttons get created dynamically with each grouping.

***EDIT**

Just adding some relevant view model code for context. If I add an identical button outside of the listview it does fire the command. [A link to an image of the whole xaml.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqZFS.png)

```
#Region "Properties"
    Public Property XCommand As ICommand
#End Region

#Region "  Constructors"
    Public Sub New(ByVal regionManager As IRegionManager, _
                   ByVal container As IUnityContainer)
        XCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf DoSomething) 
        _regionManager = regionManager
        _container = container    
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Command methods"
    Private Sub DoSomething()
        MessageBox.show("Test")
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Any help on how to get this to work correctly?

Thankyou!

Comment: Is the name shown correctly? Can you show us the relevant view model code?

Comment: Hey, added in an edit :)

Comment: Also to add to that, the same shows correctly, the grouping / headers work as intended, it's just the command firing within the header that isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're binding inside the `GroupItem` style, you're binding to the `GroupItem`'s data context. You need to bind to the view model (the ListView's data context). You can do that by using `RelativeSource`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.XCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
        Content="Add Task List" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Comment: Wow, that's honestly stumped me for a week now, there's very little you can get from a google search that doesn't provide a fix that isn't either a custom control, or a work around with click events. That's excellent, i'll read up as to why that is. Thank you!